# OOP: Object Inheritance and Composition Relationships in Simple Game Design

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

I'm currently learning Java for several reasons, but one of the main ones being that it's a very OOP orientated language, and writing code in Java is really helping me understand the core concepts behind OOP programming.

I am, however, having difficulty in defining the relationships between my classes. I understand the difference between inheritance and composition, but I'm having some difficulty seeing the whole picture, and how all of my classes should work together as a whole.

An example of how I would write a simple game of Tic-Tac Toe using OOP;

1. Create a `Game` class - creates an instance of the `gameBoard` class,
   decides who starts first, keeps track of games won and lost, starts
   and ends the game.
2. Create a `gameBoard` class - updates the tic-tac-toe board,
   determines the next player's turn, if a move is legal, and
   determines when there is a winner
3. Create an abstract `Player` class - holds the player's tile (X or O), and
   contains a method that takes a `gameBoard` instance as an argument and
   passes the move made by the player to the instance reference
4. Create a `Human` class that extends the `Player` class. Contains
   methods dealing with player input from the keyboard
5. Create a `Computer` class that extends the `Player` class. Has a
   method that takes a `gameBoard` instance as an argument and analyses
   the gameboard for a winning move, a blocking move, or any other
   move, then makes a move

This is the approach I would take. However, I'm having a little trouble relating all of the classes together. The line seems a little blurred in some cases as to where some methods and fields should belong.

**Edit:** Revised question:

What would be a good methodology in determining clear, defined roles for my classes, without getting too caught up in trying to define and ecapsulate every aspect of my program? A lot of my objects could be called from other classes to perform the specific functions that each class has, i.e `Player` updates `gameBoard`, `gameBoard` updates `Game`, but I do not know if this is good practice, or will make for rigid and hard to maintain code by passing around too many object references.

Comment: Your question is way too broad to reasonably answer. Can you boil it down further and end with a concrete question you want to have answered (as i can see a whole lot of questions in your text, each not simple to answer)?

Comment: I will try to rephrase my questions into one specific question.

Comment: From the stack overflow FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." This is not a question for stack overflow.

Comment: My question is specific, but I was finding it difficult to express it succinctly. My question is about creating clearly defined classes and readable code.

Comment: I agree with vikingsteve's answer, and he is right in saying that there is not much point in giving importance to Gameboard. Gameboard is just a passive entity which will be updated by players and evaluated by Game (or GameController).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martyn, try to classify every relationship in your problem as either "is-a" or "has-a". This will make it easier to work out the class relationships.

For example,

```
Game has-a Gameboard
Human is-a Player
Computer is-a Player
```

and then

```
Game has-a Player1
Game has-a Player2
```

etc.

See how you go with that, you'll answer many of your own questions. Good luck!

edit: you wrote: `Player` updates `gameBoard`, `gameBoard` updates `Game`

Could you do it like this, making 'Game' more central to the control of the game?

```
Game asks player to select next move from GameBoard
Player looks on Gameboard to see possible legal moves
Player selects a legal move and returns it to Game
Game plays the move on the GameBoard
Game checks the Gameboard to see if any player has won
if not, Game ends the turn and goes to the next player
...
```

Comment: I understand the has-a and is-a relationships, but it's always tempting to add in unnecessary levels of abstraction by breaking objects down further. I'm still trying to find the right balance between re-usability and abstraction.

Comment: Your class ideas are quite fine, though may I suggest making Game more central to the control of the game (see my edit).

Comment: I can see the benefit of making Game more central to overall control. It seems more natural in terms of object relationship to have Player deal with playing the move on the GameBoard, however in terms of reusability it seems logical to have the Game act as the overall controller of whatever game is being played, and would make adding additional games that extend the Game class easier to manage top-down.

Comment: Exactly. You're well on the right track now Martyn! A distant class design analogy could be MVC (used in GUI design), which also has a 'Controller'.

Comment: Funnily enough, "Controller" is exactly the word that came to mind when I read your suggestion, and from a design point of view it makes a lot of sense. I think I now have enough information to design my program. I consider my question answered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Choosing legal moves can be outsourced to Strategy classes, depending on different strategies(who gets the first move, or want to block the opponent), and used by players at runtime. I hope this addition does not over-engineer the design

Answer (score 2):

A Game has two Players and a Board. Until the board says the game is up, it should interrogate each player in turn to discover what their desired move is. It should then pass that move to the board. If the board accepts it, because it's valid, then it is the next players turn. If the board rejects the move, because it is invalid, then it asks the same player to make a move again.

This in mind, some pseudo code might take the form of;

```
class Game {
    Player p1, p2, current;
    Board board;

    public Game() {
        Board = new TicTacToeBoard();
        p1 = new Human('X');
        p2 = new Compooterwooter('O');

        current = p1;
    }
}

abstract class Player {
   char label;
   Move getMove(Board);
}

abstract class Board {
   boolean makeMove(Move);
   Position getPosition();
   boolean gameIsUp(); /* has the game finished? */
}

class Move {
   int x, y;
}

class Position {
    boolean isVacant(int x, int y);
    char whoHasPlayed(int x, int y);
}

class Human extends Player {
    Move getMove(Board b) { /* ask user for move */ }
}

class Compooterwooter extends Player {
    Move getMove(Board b) { /* compute move */
}

class TicTacToeBoard extends Board {
   boolean makeMove(int x, int y) { /* check valid move */
}
```

It's not the most useful answer, but I'm just speculating, and it seemed at least a slightly speculative question. Hopefully it will help get your mind going in the right direction.

Comment: Seeing it in pseudo code certainly does help to visualise the solution. Perhaps my problem is that I'm trying to imagine the structure in my head without planning it out first, and trying to work everything out before I start putting keystrokes to IDE. Maybe planning out my design in UML first would help me to visualise the class and object relationships better, rather than try to figure everything out before defining the structure.

Comment: It would probably help to do a little planning, yes. But equally important is to recognize that you're just learning and that you'll learn more by getting something done rather than flaffing around with UML for a day or two. Good luck with your project :-)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're quite right. I'll learn more from putting my planning into action, than over-planning.

Answer (score 1):

start with something like the code below.

then make it work so you can play both sides manually from the command line.

then refactor your code into some player classes and whatever else is needed.

```
enum State {
    x('x'),o('o'),vacant(' ');
    State(char c) {
        this.c=c;
    }
    char c;
}
class Game {
    Game() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                board[i][j]=State.vacant;
    }
    void makeMove(int i,int j,State state) {
        if(board[i][j]!=State.vacant)
            throw new RuntimeException("bad move!");
        board[i][j]=state;
    }
    boolean isGameOver() {
        // ...
        return false;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s="";
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            s+='|';
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                s+=""+board[i][j].c+'|';
            s+='\n';
        }
        return s;
    }
    final State[][] board=new State[3][3];
}
public class So15013410 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game=new Game();
        System.out.println(game);
        game.makeMove(0,0,State.x);
        System.out.println(game);
        game.makeMove(0,1,State.o);
        System.out.println(game);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It would make sense to create a usable game board first, then refactor my code to deal with player interaction, and define my classes to deal with each specific game aspect. It'll probably give me a better idea of what classes I need than try to create them all from the offset.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, as your code is has provided me with a really good starting point I can work with, as well as providing an excellent working example of enums. Much appreciated.

Comment: np, his answer is good. it relates to class relationships.